# Python - Is it possible to temporary reserve a list within a list, and return it when needed?

Tags: python

Is it  possible to temporary reserve a list within a list, and return it when needed. As I'm trying to apply it to a booking and cancellation feature to my car rental project.

```
table_car = [['Num' , 'Make/Model', 'Mileage', 'Num Passengers' , 'Num Doors' , 'Vehicel#'], 
         ['1c', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 30 , 4 , 2 , 'WGBJM5492DY'], 
         ['2c', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 30 , 4 , 2 , 'KH4M4564GD'],
         ['3c', 'Ford Fusion ', 34 , 5 , 4 , 'AB4FG5689GM'],
         ['4c', 'Ford Fusion Hybrid', 35 , 5 , 4 , 'GH2KL4278TK'],
         ['5c', 'Ford Fusion Hybrid', 32  , 5 , 4 , 'KU4EG3245RW'],
         ['6c', 'Chvrolet lmplala', 36  , 6 , 4 , 'QD4PK7394JI'],
         ['7c', 'Chvrolet lmplala', 30  , 6 , 4 , 'RK3BM4256YH']]
```

[Display of vehicles avail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y64pp.jpg)
[Vehicles that was reserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDlEa.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "reserve"?  Could you provide a little more code and indicate what you want it to do that it's not doing?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to ask? If you want to know whether you can have list inside list that you have shown in `table_car`, yes, definitely you can have, that's called nested list or 2D list.

Comment: FWIW, I think your life would be much easier if you made this a list of `NamedTuples` or `dicts` instead of a list of lists.  The format you have here is similar to what you'd get if you read a raw csv, but usually the first thing you'd do when reading a csv would be to convert it into an easier format.

Comment: The table shows 7 types of car available for booking. So when a customer books a car e.g 1c "['1c', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 30 , 4 , 2 , 'WGBJM5492DY']"  it should no longer appear or has been block off in the list. But if a customer cancels the booking, it should return back to the list.

Comment: Hi Samwise, i didn't turn it into a dict because the values then would have been categized by the keys : Make/mode =  Chevrolet Camaro , Ford Fusion ect.. I needed the values as a whole [Chevrolet Camaro', 30 , 4 , 2 , 'KH4M4564GD'].

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might model this with two dicts, one that tracks `available` cars and one that tracks `booked`cars:

```
from typing import Iterable, NamedTuple


class Car(NamedTuple):
    num: str
    make_model: str
    mileage: int
    passengers: int
    doors: int
    vin: str


all_cars = [
    Car('1c', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 30, 4, 2, 'WGBJM5492DY'),
    Car('2c', 'Chevrolet Camaro', 30, 4, 2, 'KH4M4564GD'),
    Car('3c', 'Ford Fusion ', 34, 5, 4, 'AB4FG5689GM'),
    Car('4c', 'Ford Fusion Hybrid', 35, 5, 4, 'GH2KL4278TK'),
    Car('5c', 'Ford Fusion Hybrid', 32, 5, 4, 'KU4EG3245RW'),
    Car('6c', 'Chvrolet lmplala', 36, 6, 4, 'QD4PK7394JI'),
    Car('7c', 'Chvrolet lmplala', 30, 6, 4, 'RK3BM4256YH'),
]

available = {car.num: car for car in all_cars}
booked = {}


def book(num: str) -> None:
    if num not in available:
        raise KeyError(f"{num} is not available")
    booked[num] = available[num]
    del available[num]


def cancel(num: str) -> None:
    if num not in booked:
        raise KeyError(f"{num} is not currently booked")
    available[num] = booked[num]
    del booked[num]


def print_cars(header: str, cars: Iterable[Car]) -> None:
    if not cars:
        return
    print(header)
    print("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, car)) for car in cars))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    actions = {"book": book, "cancel": cancel}
    while True:
        print_cars("Available cars:", available.values())
        print_cars("Booked cars:", booked.values())
        choice = input("> ")
        if choice.startswith("q"):
            break
        try:
            action, num = choice.split()
            assert action in actions, "commands are book, cancel, quit"
            actions[action](num)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Sample output:

```
Available cars:
1c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 WGBJM5492DY
2c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 KH4M4564GD
3c Ford Fusion  34 5 4 AB4FG5689GM
4c Ford Fusion Hybrid 35 5 4 GH2KL4278TK
5c Ford Fusion Hybrid 32 5 4 KU4EG3245RW
6c Chvrolet lmplala 36 6 4 QD4PK7394JI
7c Chvrolet lmplala 30 6 4 RK3BM4256YH
> book 4c
Available cars:
1c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 WGBJM5492DY
2c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 KH4M4564GD
3c Ford Fusion  34 5 4 AB4FG5689GM
5c Ford Fusion Hybrid 32 5 4 KU4EG3245RW
6c Chvrolet lmplala 36 6 4 QD4PK7394JI
7c Chvrolet lmplala 30 6 4 RK3BM4256YH
Booked cars:
4c Ford Fusion Hybrid 35 5 4 GH2KL4278TK
> book 5c
Available cars:
1c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 WGBJM5492DY
2c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 KH4M4564GD
3c Ford Fusion  34 5 4 AB4FG5689GM
6c Chvrolet lmplala 36 6 4 QD4PK7394JI
7c Chvrolet lmplala 30 6 4 RK3BM4256YH
Booked cars:
4c Ford Fusion Hybrid 35 5 4 GH2KL4278TK
5c Ford Fusion Hybrid 32 5 4 KU4EG3245RW
> cancel 4c
Available cars:
1c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 WGBJM5492DY
2c Chevrolet Camaro 30 4 2 KH4M4564GD
3c Ford Fusion  34 5 4 AB4FG5689GM
6c Chvrolet lmplala 36 6 4 QD4PK7394JI
7c Chvrolet lmplala 30 6 4 RK3BM4256YH
4c Ford Fusion Hybrid 35 5 4 GH2KL4278TK
Booked cars:
5c Ford Fusion Hybrid 32 5 4 KU4EG3245RW
> quit
```